# I am a US citizen. Can I gift stock options to my parents in India?

Tags: non-resident, employee-stock-options, gifts

I am a US citizen. Can I gift some stock options to my parents in India? If this is possible, could you point me to a page or document showing all things that needs to be done legally at both US and India.

Thank You.

Comment: Does the employer allow to to transfer these at all?

Answer (score 1):

From Indian taxes point of view, this transaction will come under the "Gift Tax". As per Gift Tax there is no limit on the amount that can be transferred by son to his parents. Any subsequent gains your parents make at the time of selling will be taxed to your parents depending on short term / long term capital gains.